# "file too short" on bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rvm, bundler

I'm getting occasional "file too short" messages when running `bundle exec rake`:

```
rake aborted!
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bundler/gems/amatch-0f95f4ce269f/lib/amatch_ext.so:     file too short - /var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bundler/gems/amatch-0f95f4ce269f/lib/amatch_ext.so
```

1. Is there a way to make bundler more fault-tolerant and try to re-run when it encounters these spurious failures?
2. Why might they be happening in the first place?  Multiple processes may be executing rake tasks simultaneously - can this corrupt rvm's gem repository, and if so how do I avoid the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use it in multiple processes then use `bundle --standalone` - assuming every process is ran from different path - if they all use the same path then you could try `bundle --path /path/for/gems$$/` the `$$` will be replaced with process pid - but `--path` is recorded option and this will not help as only the last run will be visible in this directory.

best would be to limit amount of runs that are performed at the same time.

other option would be modifying `GEM_HOME` at runtime, but this can get complicated with jenkins so most likely this would not work:

```
OLD_GEM_HOME=$GEM_HOME
GEM_HOME=$( mktemp -d )
cp -r $OLD_GEM_HOME/ $GEM_HOME/
bundle install
# other commands
rm -rf $GEM_HOME/
GEM_HOME=$OLD_GEM_HOME
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried your suggestion along with `bundle --path` and couldn't quite get the gems to work right.  As it turns out, though, your answer prodded me to realize that, duh, I can just create an rvm gemset for each concurrent process.  So thanks :-)